# does it matter what version of Android I have before installing Clockwordmod?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a Samsung Galaxy S with recovery 3E.  I want to install Clockworkmod on my phone, but because of the version of recovery I have, I need to flash CWM via Odin.

When I download the CWM recovery image, does it matter what version of Android I have, whether it's Froyo or Gingerbread?

Comment: I wonder if someone's made a CWM 7.1 package for Odin yet.  It would simplify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter at all for recovery.

Just make sure that if the Odin package contains anything beside CWM (e.g., a kernel) that the versions match.  I've used a Voodoo kernel with built in CWM for replacing 3E recovery, and the kernel had to be 2.2 to match my 2.2 OS.

That said, you could actually flash a mismatching kernel with CWM as long as you already had the Cyanogen package on your device and ready to install.  You'd be able to get into recovery and flash the package even if your OS wouldn't boot.

Comment: I have 2.3.3 with Hebrew support (the official version by my carrier).  Should it matter which version of Voodoo I flash, if I choose to flash CWM along with Voodoo?

Comment: @Nathan As long as it's for 2.3 and for your specific device (e.g. for the i9000 and not the T959 for example) you'll be fine.  Unless you don't care about whether the device boots, in which case you could probably flash a 2.2 Voodoo kernel as noted.

Comment: Should this affect the Hebrew support?

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure what languages CM supports.